# Limit the user to play only once a day

Tags: facebook

I am developing a card game for a Facebook app, When a matching pair is found the user gets a discount code. I need to limit all users to one game per day to prevent people winning more than 1 code a day. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
Get user's FB UID
check if it is in your database (with today's date)
  if yes: already played, deny access
  if not: insert into database (with today's date), allow access
```

Comment: Thanks  I'm a beginner at this stuff, do you know of any tutorials that could hlp me with this?

Comment: Well, I'd suggest you begin reading at the official documentation, e.g. here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/